# Show that every locally convex topological vector space is a seminormed space

Tags: functional-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

Show that every locally convex topological vector space is a seminormed space

Comment: This is not true.

Comment: Could you provide a counter example?

Comment: What is the definition of "seminormed space" that is in use? If it is "the topology is induced by a single seminorm", then the assertion is false, not every Hausdorff locally convex space is normable. If the definition is "the topology is induced by a family of seminorms", then the assertion is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a weak topology for a normed space $X$, the weak topology is generated by $p_{f}(\cdot)=\left|\left<\cdot,f\right>\right|$ for a continuous linear functional $f\in X'$, so the weak topology is a locally convex space.

And it is a standard theorem saying that, for that weak topology to be induced by a metric, a necessary and sufficient condition is that $X$ being finite dimensional.